# Finding inverse functions

Tags: function, haskell

I'm wondering whether there is a systematic/generic way to find an inverse function in Haskell.

Assuming that the function is bijective. Like:

```hs
map (+1) . map (\x -> x-1) == id
transpose . transpose == id
```

(It is interesting that funs like `transpose` and `reverse` are inverse themselves.)
We can manually find the inverse of these functions.

While functions are not bijective cannot:

```hs
f = (*0)
sum
```

I also find that functions with two params may or may not be bijections. For `map`, like `map (+1)` is bijective while `map (*0)` is not.

The composition of two bijective functions are also bijective (when considering only one param):

```hs
g = transpose . map (map (+1))
h = map (map (\x->x-1)). transpose 
g . h == id
```

(For `h = f . g`, if we can find `f'` and `g'`, then we can find `h' = g' . f'`)

So if we restrict to a *bijective* function `f :: a -> b` , is there a systematic way to find the inverse `f' :: b -> a` or inverse functions of some compositions of bijective functions?

Comment: Likely this would violate Rice's theorem.